# Past Continuous Tense vs Past Perfect Continuous Tense

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense

In the following sentences, which of the expressions in **bold** is correcet? Why is the other one not correct? How does the meaning change with each one?

> My parents got engaged in 1990. They had fallen in love two years
>   before, while they **were working/had been working** in London?

Thank you :)

Comment: They are both grammatical. But why do you think that one isn't?

Comment: became engaged is more elegant, or even: were engaged.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, the correct answer is "were working" because you used the conjunction "while".  "Had been working" would imply that they were working in London and when they had fallen in love and then they started working.

Please see the following [link](https://www.englishgrammar.org/difference-continuous-perfect-continuous-tenses/).  It explains that Past perfect continuous describes a continuous past tense event that happened BEFORE another.  You are saying that two past tense actions are occurring at the same time- *falling in love* and *working*.